# Passing an array of objects by reference to a method

Tags: php, arrays, object, pass-by-reference

I have a method in my class that accepts an object by reference. It decorates that object to extend the functionality.

basically...

```
public function addObject( &$object ) {
    $object = $this->decorate( $object );
}
```

I'm trying to write a convenience method `addObjects()` but it's not changing `$object`

This does not work...

```
public function addObjects( array &$objects ) {
    foreach( $objects as $object ) {
        $this->addObject( $object );
    }
}
```

I've tried a bunch of other routes but none have worked. I'm sure there's a way to do this, but it's escaping me. Maybe i've been staring at my computer too long.

Here's is a live example

http://ideone.com/tfopZ

---

### Update

It seems there's no way other than to pass references when creating the array of objects

```
$objects = array( &$object1, $object2 ); //object1 will be decorated, object2 will not
$thing->addObjects( $objects );
```

Comment: What happens if you set `$objects = NULL` in the function, and then `var_dump()` after the function has returned?

Comment: I just edited my answer to include another solution. Less hacky but you need to reassign your variables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**EDIT:** another solution I can think of is to reassign your local objects to the array elements, like this:

```
$dec->addObjects( $a);
$std = $a[0];
print_r( $std );
```

Now `$std` is a reference to the decorated object.

```
decorator Object
(
    [decoratee:protected] => stdClass Object
        (
        )

)
```

---

I don't have a practical solution yet, but I think I can explain the behavior.

This happens because object references are passed by value by default. So in [your example](http://ideone.com/tfopZ), the array actually contains a new reference to the object:

```
$a = array( $std );
```

So you have two references to the object:

1. One created as you initialize the object, and
2. One owned by the array.

It explains why printing `$std` gives you the same object as if it hadn't been decorated, because you are looking at `$std` *as it was created* here, which isn't the same as the one contained in the array:

```
$std = new StdClass;
```

Your `decorator` and `test` objects are working with the same object in your array, which is why dumping `$a` from your calling code produces the decorated object.

Currently the only way I can think of to coax PHP into modifying your object, is to pass it by reference to your array, like this:

```
$a = array( &$std );
```

Of course, that'll probably be a rather hacky solution and may not suit your needs.

Comment: This does work, so it is definitely the cause but you are right it's a bit hacky. I'm still searching for a better way. I've tried removing the array and adding unlimited objects using `func_get_args()` but no luck there either

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is `foreach( $objects as $object )`. This construction will make a *copy* of the array elements into `$object`. You need to do `foreach( $objects as & $object )`.

[foreach in the PHP manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

Comment: Okay, there's my PHP v4 fallback version: `foreach( $objects as $i => $na ) { $object = & $objects[i];`